# Отправка по curl в телеграм

Tags: curl, telegram

В телеграм появилась возможность отправки альбомов. Несколько фотографий отправляются как один альбом.
**Как отправить от 2 до 10 фото посредством curl в телеграм чат?**

Обширная, нет не так, Громадная документация api telegram гласит:

```
media   Array of InputMedia     Yes     A JSON-serialized array describing photos and videos to be sent, must include 2–10 items
```

Все дальше сами, куда и как слать сами разберетесь, ни одного примера нет.
Нагуглил один единственный пример на весь интернет для отправки :

```
 curl -s \
  -X POST \
  https://api.telegram.org/botKEY/sendMediaGroup\
  -F chat_id=576567test \
  -F media='[{"type":"photo","media":"/home/user/my.jpeg"},{"type":"photo","media":"/home/user/my2.jpeg"}]' \
  | jq .
```

Не помогло выходит 400 ошибка Bad Request: URL host is empty. Указание **@** перед путями файлов тоже не помогло. Если вместо **sendMediaGroup**  написать **sendPhoto** тоже не работает.

Подскажите как правильно по curl отправлять альбомы фоток в чаты телеграм?

Answer (score 1):

Документация гласит:

> Pass a file_id to send a file that exists on the Telegram servers
>   (recommended), pass an HTTP URL for Telegram to get a file from the
>   Internet, or pass “attach://” to upload a new one using
>   multipart/form-data under name. нужно добавить attach://

Проверил, работает:

```
#!/bin/bash

TOKEN="687895627:AAEjuHWsNu8chKxLm94VOoYRmyBmue5RKi8"
CHAT_ID="38762912"

file1='/var/www/html/img/bb-lowsize-comp.png'
file2='/var/www/html/img/saw1.jpg'

image1="attach://"$(basename $file1)
image2="attach://"$(basename $file2)

curl -s -X POST -F media='[{"type":"photo","media":"'$image1'"},    {"type":"photo","media":"'$image2'"}]' \
    -F "$(basename $file1)=@${file1}" -F "$(basename $file2)=@${file2}" -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" \
    "https://api.telegram.org/bot$TOKEN/sendMediaGroup?chat_id=$CHAT_ID"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ выше у меня не заработал

Немного переделал его и получилось следующим образом:

```
#!/bin/bash
TOKEN="999999999999:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
CHAT_ID="-XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
file='/path/to/file.jpg'
curl -s -X POST -F media='[{"type":"photo","media":"attach://photo"}]' -F photo=@$file -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" https://api.telegram.org/bot$TOKEN/sendMediaGroup?chat_id=$CHAT_ID
```

Возможно вам это не подойдет - мне нужно отправить только 1 фото

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развернутые ответы.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).